# "It have looked" - Is it correct sentence?

Tags: present-perfect, subject-verb-agreement

> It have looked like i was running away.

Is this correct?

And if it is, why?

I tried to find the answer, but I couldn't. All the dictionaries tell me that it's correct, but why isn't it "It has looked"?

Comment: Which dictionary?  Dictionaries usually only give meanings of words.  They don't check grammar.  Do you mean a spelling and grammar checker?  Which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*It have looked like I was running away* is not grammatical. *It* is the (dummy) subject, and requires the 3rd person auxiliary *has*.

Either your dictionaries are wrong, or this is embedded in some larger syntactic unit that you are not telling us.

Separately, *It has looked like* is not idiomatic in most contexts: we don't usually use the "present perfect" with verbs that express states.

**Edit**: it occurs to me that this could occur in the sentence *Could it have looked like I was running away?* which is both grammatical and idiomatic. The finite verb is the modal *could* (which has no distinct third person form, being a modal), and the *have* is the base form following a modal.

Answer (score 2):

"It have looked..." is incorrect.

"It has looked like I was running away" is a grammatically correct, but normally unnatural sentence.

You would naturally use the past tense "It looked like I was running away."